# Upgrading to Guice 4 in Play app now seeing "No implementation for CLASSNAME was bound."

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I'm upgrading a project from Play 2.3.x -> 2.4.x and consequently, having to update a jar dependency from Guice 3.x to 4.x.

I'm injecting the services in the controller like this with Guice:

```
import javax.inject._

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(service: MyService) extends Controller
```

The `configure()` method for guice bindings in my jar looks like this (just a sample provided here):

```
bind(classOf[MyService]).in(classOf[Singleton])
bind(classOf[OtherService]).in(classOf[Singleton])
```

Just want to reiterate that those bindings are defined in a separate jar that is a dependency of my play project. Injection works fine using a service that is already defined in guice bindings (MyService or OtherService)

```
import com.google.inject.Inject

class MyService @Inject()(otherService: OtherService)
```

But will fail if I add any other dependency that is manually constructed using the `AbstractModule` interface like this:

```
def configure() {
    val config = getConfig
    bind(classOf[Config]).toInstance(config)
}
```

And injected into `MyService` like so:

```
class MyService @Inject()(otherService: OtherService, config: Config) with InitializingBean
```

during dependency injection at runtime I get the following error:

`No implementation for Config was bound.`

Any idea why Guice 3.0 -> 4.0 upgrade would cause this? Or any ideas I can explore as next step? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Added an answer, please check if it does solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you import the class

`import models.userClass`

Then inject your classes/traits at the Class declaration line, and not in the body of the class:

`class MyClass @Inject()(val config: Configuration, var userClass: UserClass){...}`

If it is the controller class you should extend it with `InjectedController`.

Comment: Looks like InjectedController is not yet available as a trait in Play 2.4.x